# ARM register definition S3_0_C12_C12_7

Tags: arm

There are ARM64 registers like S3_0_C12_C12_1 defined in [ATF](https://github.com/ARM-software/arm-trusted-firmware/blob/master/include/arch/aarch64/arch.h) code (ARM trusted firmware)

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Definitions for CPU system register interface to GICv3
 ******************************************************************************/
#define ICC_IGRPEN1_EL1     S3_0_C12_C12_7
#define ICC_SGI1R       S3_0_C12_C11_5
#define ICC_SRE_EL1     S3_0_C12_C12_5
#define ICC_SRE_EL2     S3_4_C12_C9_5
#define ICC_SRE_EL3     S3_6_C12_C12_5
#define ICC_CTLR_EL1        S3_0_C12_C12_4
#define ICC_CTLR_EL3        S3_6_C12_C12_4
#define ICC_PMR_EL1     S3_0_C4_C6_0
#define ICC_RPR_EL1     S3_0_C12_C11_3
#define ICC_IGRPEN1_EL3     S3_6_c12_c12_7
#define ICC_IGRPEN0_EL1     S3_0_c12_c12_6
```

But I am not able find any document about these S3_0_C4_C6_0 definitions. Does anybody know the information of them? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest official list of System Registers and their detailed descriptions is available on the [Exploration Tools page](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/cpu-architecture/a-profile/exploration-tools) of the ARM WEB site.

`ICV_IGRPEN1_EL1` is recognized for example by GNU AS as `s3_0_c12_c12_7` because
the values specified in the ARM documentation for `op0`, `op1`, `CRn`, `CRm` and `op2` are:

```
op0     op1     CRn     CRm     op2
0b11    0b000   0b1100  0b1100  0b111
```

Once converted in decimal:

```
   3        0       12      12      7
```

Bottom line, official names for the registers you are mentioning are:

```
ICC_CTLR_EL1 (s3_0_c12_c12_4)
ICC_CTLR_EL3 (s3_6_c12_c12_4)
ICC_IGRPEN0_EL1 (s3_0_c12_c12_6)
ICC_IGRPEN1_EL1 (s3_0_c12_c12_7)
ICC_IGRPEN1_EL3 (s3_6_c12_c12_7)
ICC_PMR_EL1 (s3_0_c4_c6_0)
ICC_RPR_EL1 (s3_0_c12_c11_3)
ICC_SGI1R_EL1 (s3_0_c12_c11_5)
ICC_SRE_EL1 (s3_0_c12_c12_5)
ICC_SRE_EL2 (s3_4_c12_c9_5)
ICC_SRE_EL3 (s3_6_c12_c12_5)
ICV_CTLR_EL1 (s3_0_c12_c12_4)
ICV_IGRPEN0_EL1 (s3_0_c12_c12_6)
ICV_IGRPEN1_EL1 (s3_0_c12_c12_7)
ICV_PMR_EL1 (s3_0_c4_c6_0)
ICV_RPR_EL1 (s3_0_c12_c11_3)
```

Comment: You are welcome. Since that was your first question, I would suggest you to read this post: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).